# Dynamicly create facebook thumbnails in WordPress theme

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, thumbnails

The facebook suggests to put an :og metatag inside your page, but I need to create it dynamicly for each WordPress post/single - but in header I am not in the loop yet - how do I get the page/single thumbnail, while not in loop yet ? :)

**I ended up with:**

```
<?php global $post; $id = $post->ID; ?>
<meta name="og:image" content="<?php 
   $thumbieLink = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id) ); 
   if( $thumbieLink!==false && $thumbieLink!="" ) echo $thumbieLink;
      else echo "http://IfNoThumbNailIsAvailable.com/default.jpg"; 
?>" />
```

Reason why I use a bit different meta tag than the standard is because I dont want to add XHTML doctype to my site - see http://code.adonline.id.au/valid-meta-tags-for-facebook-link-thumbnails/ for more info :) XML is great, XHTML is evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
global $post;
$id = $post->ID;
```

You can use this anywhere outside of the loop to get the post/page id. 
Now you can use the standard Wordpress functions to get the featured image, post excerpt etc.

```
$imageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id) );
```

With this line you get the featured image url. Now you can echo the og:image tag that facebook requires.